# Question on Recurrence $T^2(n) = T(n/2) * T(2n) - T(n) * T(n/2)$

Tags: recurrence-relation

Need help solving this recurrence:

$T^2(n) = T(n/2) * T(2n) - T(n) * T(n/2)$

Comment: Your recurrence isn't well-founded.

Comment: $T(n)$ relies on $T(2n)$, and $T(2n)$ relies on $T(4n)$, and so on...

Comment: Where did you encounter this recurrence?  By some algebraic manipulation, we see

$$T(2n) = {T^2(n) \over T(n/2)} + T(n).$$

After substituting, this has the form

$$T(n) = {T^2(n/2) \over T(n/4)} + T(n/2).$$